# how to send mail to an email id in android?

Tags: android

In my project i have to send mail to company id.First i tried code with my email id. but its not showing anything.my code is here

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);        
String aEmailList[] = { "my emailid used here" };  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject"); 
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");       
startActivity(emailIntent);
Log.e("name","msg sent success fully");
```

in my logcat i saw "msg sent success fully" message also. but i didnt get any mail in my mail id.
am i did any wrong code or am i need to add any permissions in manifest file.

Comment: have you given INTERNET permission in Androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: can you please upload your xml code as well ?

Comment: @Lucifer lol, you're so wrong ... sowjanyarendla ... "msg sent success fully" <= this message is misleading ... your code just starts intent

Comment: i checked on device its gave me choices(gmail,bluetooth,messaging) i selected bluetooth. still i am not found in my mail

Comment: instead of startActivity use startActivityForResult ... read startActivityForResult documentation to know how to get response from started activity

Comment: <Linearlayout><EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:hint="Email address"
android:layout_width="170dip" android:id="@+id/emailaddress"/> 
 <EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:hint="subject"
android:layout_width="170dip" android:id="@+id/emailsubject"/> 
<EditText android:hint="emailtext"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:lines="5" android:layout_width="300dip"
android:id="@+id/emailtext"/>   
<Button 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/emailsendbutton"
android:text="Send!"
android:layout_width="150dip"/></Linearlayout>

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine except there is no need to use "android.content." and there is no FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK What should happen is that your email program should start with these data already entered. Have you setup your email client on that device?

Here is a code example that works and sends an image selected from a gallery as an attachment:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
i.setType("image/png");  
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + mUrls[imageSelected].toString()));  
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: actually i forgot to configure my account on device. now my code wrking properly